# How to get list of tables, views etc. a users has rights to on Sybase IQ?

Tags: sybase, sybaseiq

I'm looking for a way to get a list of views, tables, procesdures etc, a user has been granted to. A select onto `SYSROLEGRANTS` helped me to find basic role of users -- but not more like this.

So e.g. Having this:

```
create or replace view myFancyView as
SELECT * from mytable;

GRANT SELECT ON myFancyView TO myUser;
```

I'm hoping for a list like that:

```
|User  | Right                |
|------|----------------------|
|MyUser| SELECT ON myFancyView|
```

Comment: http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38151.1600/doc/html/jcu1329143557191.html  <---Lists all the system views, as what you are looking for is going to require joining multiple views together (`sysprocperm`, `systableperm`, etc. etc.)

Answer (score 1):

http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36273.1570/html/sprocs/X22708.htm lists the system stored procedure, `sp_helprotect` which provides a mechanism for displaying all the rights a user has in a given database.

From that document:

> Displays all the permissions that “judy” has in the database:
>
> sp_helprotect judy

Comment: This seems to be only on ASE, not IQ which is more like an ASA at thsi point.